# Center custom bullets of a ul

Tags: html, css, html-lists

How can I arrange the bullets of my ul-List horizontally? They are like on the bottom and I want to have them in the middle. 
[image]

The bullet I used is a SVG.

I searched all around the web but didn't find something.

**EDIT 1:**

This is my code (not much, but anyways):

```
ul {
    list-style-image: url('newBullet.svg');
  }
```

**EDIT 2:**
after this code:

```
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/css/sqpurple.gif');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-y: 12px;

  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

it looks like this, when the text in the li-element 2 rows (it goes in the middle of both rows):

[image]

Comment: You should be able to use background-position to change where the bullet goes.

Comment: @JensV Do you have an example?

Comment: Added as an answer, the comment was kinda useless without context sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using list-style you can use a background image and position it correctly. Like so:

```
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-image: url('newBullet.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-y: center;

  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/o2wyj5ey/

### Multiline

If your listitem has multiple lines you can absolutely position them like this:

```
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/css/sqpurple.gif');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-y: 3px;

  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/o2wyj5ey/1/

Comment: Now its in the middle, thank you. But I have multiline List-elements and the bullet is like in the middle of the hole think. Do you have a solution for that aswell?

Comment: @minimen Instead of center for the background position, set it to like 3px or the value that goes well for your image. Then it should always be at the same position.